# NodeJS async. Header sent before Object is properly formed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm having troubles using asynchronous calls. This is the code snippet that's been giving me problems

```
company.find({ managerID: req.session.manager.managerID })
        .exec((err, _companies) => {
            if(err)
                return res.status(500).send({ message: "Uh, oh! Something went wrong." });
            else {
                var data = [];
                var i = 0;
                _companies.forEach(c => {
                    user.find({ companyID: c._id, status: 0})
                    .then(_user => {
                            // console.log(_user);
                            var dummy = {
                                companyID: c._id,
                                companyName: c.companyName,
                                selectedCurrency: c.selectedCurrency,
                                metrics: c.metrics,
                                headAdmin: _user[0].email,
                                headName: _user[0].designer
                            };
                            console.log(dummy);
                            data.push(dummy);
                            console.log(data);
                            i++;
                    }).catch(err => {
                        return res.status(500).send({ message: "Uh, oh! Something went wrong." });
                    });
                });
                if(i == _companies.length)
                    return res.status(200).send({ data: data });
            }
        });
```

my data Object is being sent before the object is properly formed.

I have tried switching from .exec to .then promise in hopes it might fix it and even tried to return only after the loop has finished(doesn't even return an empty array).

Whenever i call a `console.log("hi")` before `return res.status(200).send({ data: data})` it always gets printed before `console.log(dummy)`

would await fix this problem and if yes, how should i use it, becouse i'm not familiar on how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach` works synchronously so it does not wait for async operations inside it such as `user.find()`. Therefore, `i == _companies.length` evaluates to `true` before async operations are completed.

As suggested in the other answer you can resolve this issue by collecting all the pending promises in an array and passing it to [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). In your scenario this may look something like as follows:

```
company.find({ managerID: req.session.manager.managerID })
  .exec((err, _companies) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: "Uh, oh! Something went wrong." });
    }
    const results = _companies.map(c =>
      user.find({ companyID: c._id, status: 0})
        .then(_user => ({
            companyID: c._id,
            companyName: c.companyName,
            selectedCurrency: c.selectedCurrency,
            metrics: c.metrics,
            headAdmin: _user[0].email,
            headName: _user[0].designer
        }))
    );
    return Promise.all(results)
      .then(data => res.status(200).send({ data: data }))
      .catch((err) => res.status(500).send({ message: "Uh, oh! Something went wrong." }));
  });
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for, becouse i was extremelly unfamiliar with how to use Promises. Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: @Yoshy I am glad to know that it was helpful, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

That's because your forEach has asynchronous instructions inside any loop. So basically forEach is synchronous, but you've inserted here promises and your next instructions executes after all loops in forEach happened

In case you use Bluebird promises(sequential execution)

```
Promise.mapSeries(_companies, c => /*generate data*/)
.then(res.status(200).send({ data: data }))
```

Or using Promise.all(parallel execution)

```
Promise.all(_companies.map(c => /*generate data*/)
.then(res.status(200).send({ data: data }))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bluebird, sorry. If possible i want to avoid downloading a new package just for 1 error, but i will take it into account. Thank you.

Comment: You can do it with ordinary Promises

also `async/await` could help to make your code more clean and use `await` inside the loop or map

like: `await Promise.all(_companies.map(c => /*promise expression*/))`